# iOS detect other device over WiFi

Tags: ios, wireless

I am new to iOS development and I am still learning iOS development by myself. I was thinking 
is it possible for iOS device to detect other WiFi enabled device(android/iOS device) using iPhone's WiFi only?

The book I am currently reading is on iOS 7. So I will be developing iOS 7 app.

Comment: Also look into this apple's [Bonjour Api](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)

Comment: With ios 7 Apple said - ["Let there be the Multipeer connectivity"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013328)

Comment: Thanks guys... I will be looking into it :D
Can anyone also recommend any good book or webpage for learning iOS 7 and objective C?

Comment: @user2763829, This is an off topic question. That being mentions; there are a number of great sites out there. For me, when I learned I found it most effective to work through tutorials building simple apps (bonus if the tutorials have something to do with the one you are building) any tutorial will help from the begining.  Tutsplus, http://www.raywenderlich.com/, and of course stackoverflow work out great. Good luck. :)